# Not Getting Image By GET method in spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Here is my entity class

```
@ToString
@Data
@Entity
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String description;
    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] image;
}
```

Here is my Controller class where I post product information to the MySQL database with name , price , description and product image

```
@PostMappig("/product")
public Products uploadProducts(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("price") BigDecimal price,
        @RequestParam("description") String description, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image,
        @RequestParam("categorys") Categorys thecategory) throws IOException {

    byte[] imageData;

    imageData = image.getBytes();

    Products products = new Products();

    products.setName(name);
    products.setPrice(price);
    products.setDescription(description);
    products.setCategorys(thecategory);
    products.setImage(image);

    return productRepository.save(products);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get product information with product image by GET Method By Using JAVA spring JPA?

You can create DTO class for your entity class:

```
@Data
public class ProductDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String description;
    private byte[] image;
}
```

And then create HTTP GET RestApi method in your RestController:

```
..
...
....
@GetMapping("/product/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ProductDTO> getProduct(@PathVariable int id) {
    Optional<Products> productOptional = productRepository.findById(id);
    
    if (productOptional.isPresent()) {
        Products product = productOptional.get();
        
        ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
        productDTO.setId(product.getId());
        productDTO.setName(product.getName());
        productDTO.setPrice(product.getPrice());
        productDTO.setDescription(product.getDescription());
        productDTO.setImage(product.getImage());
        
        return ResponseEntity
                  .ok(productDTO);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity
                  .notFound()
                  .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but not worked the Image will come in string not in jpg or Png form.

Comment: @MrStranger what is your expected result?

Comment: I want Json Object with all keys and values including imags like { "name" : "iPhone", "price" : 1200 , "description" : "from apple" ,  "image" : [image]}